# Prioritizing wp enqueue scripts error

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, actions

I wanted to load the following two scripts before any other script so I added priority 1 and 2, however I am getting an error. I read it on a [tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/) that this is how to prioritize

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(__CLASS__, 'frontend_enqueues', 1));
        add_action('print_head_scripts', array(__CLASS__, 'print_js', 2));
```

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, array must have exactly two members in
>   xxx/xx/xxx/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, array must have exactly two members in
>   xxx/xx/xxx/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 173

Please advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got parentheses levels slightly wrong and that broke your callbacks.

It should be:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'frontend_enqueues' ), 1 );
```